# Magento 2: How to add an afterRender option to a template rendered by a LayoutProcessPlugin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7, knockoutjs

I want to add an `afterRender` callback to the `delivery_time_slot` element. However I am not sure how to do this using the `LayoutProcessorPlugin.php`. Is this added through the `LayoutProcessorPluging.php` or from the `select.html` template? 
Also where do I include the callback method? In the select component js file?

I have extended both the element template and the component for the select form element.

**LayoutProcessorPlugin.php**

```
        if($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_REVIEW_PAYMENTS){
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children']['delivery_time_slot'] = [
                'component' => 'MyVendor_MyModule/js/form/element/select',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'MyVendor_MyModule/form/element/select',
                    'id' => 'delivery-time-slot'
                ],
                'caption' => 'Please select delivery time slot',
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_time_slot',
                'label' => 'Delivery Time Slot',
                'notice' => 'Need it by today? Anything is possible, it\'s just a phone call away',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'options' => $this->_helper->getTimeSlot(),
                'sortOrder' => 201,
                'id' => 'delivery-time-slot',
            ];
        }else{
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children'][$container]['children']['delivery_time_slot'] = [
                'component' => 'MyVendor_MyModule/js/form/element/select',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'MyVendor_MyModule/form/element/select',
                    'id' => 'delivery-time-slot'
                ],
                'caption' => 'Please select delivery time slot',
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_time_slot',
                'label' => 'Delivery Time Slot',
                'notice' => 'Need it by today? Anything is possible, it\'s just a phone call away',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'options' => $this->_helper->getTimeSlot(),
                'sortOrder' => 201,
                'id' => 'delivery-time-slot',
            ];
        }
```

**MyVendor/MyModule/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'MyVendor_MyModule/js/view/shipping',
    'MyVendor_MyModule/js/order-delivery-date'
], function ($,
             ko,
             Select,
             Shipping,
             OrderDeliveryDate
) {
    'use strict';

    ko.bindingHandlers.timeSlotBinding = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            OrderDeliveryDate.saveTimeSlots();
            OrderDeliveryDate.datePickerRadioTrigger();
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            OrderDeliveryDate.datePickerRadioTrigger();
        }
    }

    return Select.extend({

    });


});
```

**MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/select.html**

```
<select class="admin__control-select" data-bind="
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        placeholder: placeholder
    },
    timeSlotBinding: value
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    value: value,
    optionsCaption: caption,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label'"
        />
```

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add do this by using the `afterRender` custom binding. In `select.html`, and in the `data-bind` attribute, add: `afterRender: yourMethod()`.

Create a `yourMethod()` function inside the returned object of `select.js`:

```
return Select.extend({
    yourMethod: function() {
        console.log('action');
    }
});
```